FrankenPHP / Caddy under Docker - unable to use cURL with internal name
I have a Symfony 7.1 application that runs API Platform 4. This app (core) is used for a bunch of other Dockerised applications to write/read data to the database and run some other business logic.
It's setup to run under FrankenPHP 1.2.5 / PHP 8.3. I then have another Symfony application in another container (called app). Both containers run in separate compose.yml files, but are joined by bother projects being on the same Docker network.
From here, i want to access the API from core using the internal name, e.g.:
<?php
// In a controller
public function testAction(HttpClientInterface $client): Response
{
    $data = $client->request(
        'GET',
        'https://core/api/report/company/statistics',
        // Added for testing, but don't help
        ['verify_host' => false, 'verify_peer' => false]
    );
}

I get the error message:
OpenSSL/3.1.6: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error for "https://core/api/report/company/statistics".

If I get inside the app container in a shell, I try to run the following:
var/www/html # curl --insecure -vI https://core/api/report/company/statistics
* Host core:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 172.24.0.12
*   Trying 172.24.0.12:443...
* Connected to core (172.24.0.12) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, internal error (592):
* OpenSSL/3.1.6: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error
* Closing connection
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.1.6: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error

I've also run the following:
/var/www/html # openssl s_client -connect core:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
08EB0452797F0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 293 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

To be clear, this is whilst I'm developing, so I'm not concerned about SSL errors - I'm happy to ignore them. However, even trying to ignore them doesn't seem to work.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue with FrankenPHP / Caddy in trying to ignore the SSL issues when developing?
